# SSIS - Faster ways to load data from one SQL server to another

Tags: sql-server, ssis, integration, etl

I have an SSIS package that is responsible to load the different tables from source to destination SQL server. Source and destination have the same number of columns.

However, there are tables that hold more than 3 million rows of data.

But the package takes more than 30 minutes to load 500K rows of data.

I know there are ways to speed up the data load faster from the bit of online searching for solutions.
But your help and suggestions will be appreciated. Please see below for the properties of DFT.

- **Data Source:** OLEDB Source - Azure SQL server
- **Destination:** OLEDB Destination - Local SQL server
- **DefaultBufferMaxRows** = 100000
- **DefaultBufferSize** = 99485760(99MB)
- **AutoAdjustBufferSize** = True
- **EngineThreads** = 10

Comment: Make sure you're using the OLE DB Destination fast load option.

Comment: @DanGuzman - Yes, it is the OLEDB destination with the fast load option

Comment: Replace the destination with a Derived Column destination and run it. How long does that take? (This helps you identify your max theoretical speed). How is the target table defined? Does it have multiple indexes? Does it have a clustered key? If yes to cluster, are the inserts from the data load appending or does it need to spit pages to make it happen? Is there activity on the target table when the ETL is running? Are you using a truncate and reload pattern or is the destination an incremental load?

Comment: @billinkc -  Target is the staging table that has 150 column named col1...col150

It does not have indexes or any keys.

Single DFT gets the query from variable and executes on the Azure SQL server. Here OLEDB Source takes a long time to pull the data.  Then inserting into the destination is quick and fast.

I am not sure why SQL Query takes a long time to execute on the Azure SQL Server

Comment: So you've identified that the source query is the laggard in this scenario. So, why is it slow? Is there concurrent activity against the source table blocking your select (check your isolation level)? What is the product/service tier of your database in azure - could you be bumping up against the DTU cap (scale up to a higher tier and then run the ETL with the scale back down - assuming your system can handle the scale down hiccup)

Comment: I used a different approach to pull the data. SQL query pulls data into JSON format by each row and stores JSON string into a staging table. Also, I changed the following properties of the Data Flow Task

DefaultBufferMaxRows = 1000

DefaultBufferSize = 1048576(1MB)

Now to integrate 500K rows takes 11 seconds reduced from 19 minutes.